# Zend Framework, Validation of password

Tags: zend-framework

I have a case: register form has a few fields, eg. firstname, lastname, passsword, passwordConfirm. When user didn't fill lastname field, after submit the form and reload we have validation error in box about empty lastname. In this step, the user has to fill empty lastname field but also password and passwordConfirm fields again (these fields are cleared after every reload), but the user doesn't have an alert about refill passwords, because in previous step passwords field was entered correctly. Is any way to mark passwords fields in this case as fields to fill again?

Answer (score 0):

in you  controller you need to use method setData(), this method allow you maintain data in you form.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html